# How to make SAPUI5 TreeTable expanded by default?

Tags: expand, sapui5, treetable

I use following code (in controller):

```
onAfterRendering: function () {
    var t, i;
    if (!this.initExpand) {
        try {
            t = this.getView().getContent()[1];
            for (i=0; i<t.getRows().length; i++) {
                t.expand(i);
            }
            this.initExpand = true;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("expand failed: "+e.message);
        }
    }
},
```

for initial (after loading and rendering) expanding all nodes of following sap.ui.table.TreeTable (in view):

```
<mvc:View
    displayBlock="true" 
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:table="sap.ui.table"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    controllerName="sap.app.controller.scr1"
>
    <l:HorizontalLayout>
        <SearchField liveChange="onSearch"/>
    </l:HorizontalLayout>
    <table:TreeTable rows="{/root}"
        selectionMode="None"
        visibleRowCount="11"
        showColumnVisibilityMenu="true"
        enableCellFilter="true"
        enableColumnReordering="false"
        class="sapUiSizeCompact"
        expandFirstLevel="true"
    >
        <table:columns>
        ...
        </table:columns>
    </table:TreeTable>
</mvc:View>
```

But sometimes nodes still are not expanded (remains collapsed).

**Is there some other (more stable) way for initial expanding all nodes of sap.ui.table.TreeTable?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code works:

```
onAfterRendering: function(){

   var oTreeTable = this.getView().byId("myTreeTableId");
   oTreeTable.expandToLevel(3); //number of the levels of the tree table.

}
```

Where '3' is the number of the levels for your tree table and,

myTreeTableId: is the Id of your control at XML view:

```
<table:TreeTable id="myTreeTableId" ...
```

Comment: I cannot to get this TreeTable object with the function byId because id of this TreeTable (contatenated with id of the view) is dynamic (changes). However, this.getView().getContent()[1].expandToLevel(3); truly always works! Thanks for the answer, @carlosmendes-pt!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this [demo](http://jsbin.com/nadolam/edit?html,output).

```
/* code to expand */  
for (i=0; i<oTable.getRows().length; i++) {
    oTable.expand(i);
}
```

Comment: What is difference between your "for" loop and my "for" loop? "oTable" is more stable than "t"?

Comment: Though I'm not sure about this, I just wanted to suggest you to use Table's object instead of getting an element from `content` aggregation of view. see if it works!

Comment: I have added also xml code where you can see that this.getView().getContent()[1] is TreeTable object. I cannot to get this TreeTable object with the function byId because id of this TreeTable (contatenated with id of the view) is dynamic (changes).